# Mini puzzle IP header

Tags: c, ip, c-preprocessor

Look at the following code :

```
#define IP_HL(ip)       (((ip)->ip_vhl) & 0x0f)
#define IP_V(ip)        (((ip)->ip_vhl) >> 4)
```

full code here http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

I understand that out of 8 bits in `ip_vhl`:

- `IP_HL` does & operation with 0000 1111, which means that we get the last four bits
- `IP_V` shifts a bit patter to the right by four bits, ehich also give us last four bits...

I checked code and it works fine: it shows 4 for IP Version and 5 for Header size...

How does it return a different number?
What is wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `IP_V` shifts a bit pattern to the right by four bits, which give us *first* four bits (assuming, as you do, that it's an 8-bit value).

In more detail, assume the bit pattern `abcdefgh`:

```
  abcd efgh         abcd efgh
& 0000 1111              >> 4
  =========         =========
  0000 efgh         0000 abcd
```

The `>> 4` operation throws away bits exiting on the right hand side and feeds in `0` bits at the left hand side. Hence, right-shifthing that value a bit at a time would give:

```
abcd efgh     --> direction of shift
0abc defg
00ab cdef
000a bcde
0000 abcd
```

Comment: sorry, do not understand :) can you give an example

Comment: thanks, I will put yours as answer as you were first

Comment: @maximilliano, don't accept an answer because it's the _first,_ SO is a meritocracy, you should accept it because it's the _best._ You should still accept it, of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you your bits is 0011 0101 then >> 4 will get you 0000 0011 as you have moved everything to the right 4 places, and lost the 0101 bits.